# Why calendar api does not create last day of recurrence?

Tags: node.js, datetime, google-calendar-api

When I'm trying to create recurring event, the last day of recurrence is not being created.
However, it is only when I provide startDateTime later than 3AM, if earlier everything works.

**For example: this below does not create**

```
start: { dateTime: '2022-07-13T03:04:00', timeZone: 'Europe/Kiev' },
```

How it looks in calendar ( incorrect request with time 3:04AM )

[image: How it looks in calendar ( incorrect request with time 3:04AM )]

**And this one creates**

```
start: { dateTime: '2022-07-13T03:00:00', timeZone: 'Europe/Kiev' },
```

How it looks in calendar ( working request with time 3AM)

[image: How it looks in calendar ( working request with time 3AM)]
I think it is allocated to my timezone, which is just +3

**This below is not working request**

```
{
  summary: 'Draft #0',
  creator: { displayName: 'Test' },
  start: { dateTime: '2022-07-13T03:04:00', timeZone: 'Europe/Kiev' },
  end: { dateTime: '2022-07-13T23:58:00', timeZone: 'Europe/Kiev' },
  recurrence: [
    'EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20220713',
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20220719;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU'
  ]
}
```

If we change in this request **start.dateTime** to 0-3AM everything is fine.

What shall I do in order to create this one last day?

Comment: sounds weird what timezone is the calendar set to?

Comment: Google Calendar is also set to Europe/Kiev Timezone ( If you meen web version )

Comment: This sounds strange to me i would bug report it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191627%2B

Comment: I`ll create google issue, thank you

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236615807

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Support Answered:

> Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior) Hello,
>
> This behavior is being closed as intended.
>
> Please note that UNTIL instructs that ideally the events should be
> created only before that time or if the times are coinciding, the
> UNTIL is the last occurrence of that event. No event would be created
> after the UNTIL threshold is reached.
>
> For Kiev, the timezone is UTC+0300 For events which start at 03:00 or
> before, the last day of the recurring event does get created. For
> events which start after 0300, the event is NOT created since the
> UNTIL parameter restricts the creation. Configure the UNTIL timezone
> to use the last event's required start time.
>
> To be able to make an event on 20220719, you can configure the UNTIL
> clause as UNTIL=20220719T030400Z
>
> Regards